# Equivalent of GREATEST() function in MS-Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there an equivalent `[GREATEST()]`[1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-numeric-functions.htm#function_greatest) function that I can code into an MS-Access SQL statement?  I have a table of project numbers with several date fields.  I want to return an output that specifies the most recent date.  Effectively this indicates the status of a particular project.

```sql
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| ProjectNum | CondCommit | FirmCommit | FundAgt   | Disbursemt | Servicing |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| 1898       |            | 1/30/2008  | 2/21/2008 | 6/18/2008  | 6/21/2010 |
| 1906       | 12/20/2004 | 5/19/2006  | 5/3/2006  | 4/6/2006   | 4/5/2007  |
| 1918       | 3/31/2009  | 11/19/2009 | 3/24/2010 | 12/22/2010 |           |
| 1956       | 3/31/2009  |            | 3/5/2010  |            |           |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

I know I can use a `SWITCH` function that will compare just two dates, but I have to find the most recent date among five fields.  Ideally I would like an output that looks like this:

```sql
+------------+------------+------------+
| ProjectNum | Status     | StatusDt   |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 1898       | Servicing  | 6/21/2010  |
| 1906       | Servicing  | 4/5/2007   |
| 1918       | Disbursemt | 12/22/2010 |
| 1956       | FundAgt    | 3/5/2010   |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

I'm willing to try any variety of functions, but I would like to keep the code within SQL.  If I have to send the output to another application for processing, that kinda defeats the purpose of using SQL to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution:

1. Create a table called `Status` with a column called `Status`. Fill this with unique statuses.
2. For the sake of this exercise, I'm calling your input table (the first one you listed) as `table1`

Your code can be as follows:

```
select
    i.ProjectNum
    ,oo.Status
    ,i.StatusDt
from (
            select
                o.ProjectNum
                ,Max(o.StatusDt) as StatusDt
            from (
                select 
                    t.ProjectNum
                    ,t.[Status]
                    ,iif(t.[Status] = 'CondCommit',a.CondCommit,
                        iif(t.[Status] = 'FirmCommit',a.FirmCommit,
                            iif(t.[Status] = 'FundAgt',a.FundAgt,
                                iif(t.[Status] = 'Disbursemt',a.Disbursemt,
                                    iif(t.[Status] = 'Servicing',a.Servicing,null))))) as StatusDt
                from 
                (
                select 
                    table1.ProjectNum
                    ,Status.Status
                from table1, Status
                ) as t
                inner join table1 as a
                    on t.ProjectNum = a.ProjectNum
            ) as o
            group by o.ProjectNum
    ) as i
    inner join (
            select 
                t.ProjectNum
                ,t.[Status]
                ,iif(t.[Status] = 'CondCommit',a.CondCommit,
                    iif(t.[Status] = 'FirmCommit',a.FirmCommit,
                        iif(t.[Status] = 'FundAgt',a.FundAgt,
                            iif(t.[Status] = 'Disbursemt',a.Disbursemt,
                                iif(t.[Status] = 'Servicing',a.Servicing,null))))) as StatusDt
            from 
            (
            select 
                table1.ProjectNum
                ,Status.Status
            from table1, Status
            ) as t
            inner join table1 as a
                on t.ProjectNum = a.ProjectNum
    ) as oo
    on i.ProjectNum = oo.ProjectNum
    and i.StatusDt = oo.StatusDt
```

Note:

- You can (an probably should) save the subqueries as separate queries, and then just simplify the query above by citing the subquery names.
- However - my original SQL can run as-is.

Comment: Thanks very much.  It appears that this query will always pick the right-most date, regardless if it is actually the most recent date.  Can this be modified so it actually picks the "greatest" date?  Ideally the status will always flow "left to right," but there are exceptions, and I'd like to be able to catch that using this query.

Comment: My mistake, it performs exactly as advertised.  (I just needed to be more careful refreshing the tables)

Comment: I know I'm not exactly following your advice, but I'm having a bit of trouble implementing the solution as a fully nested query.  You may have some good insight. [Implementing nesting query rather than sub-query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430559/implementing-nesting-query-rather-than-sub-query)

Comment: @Sponge I answered your question - please check it out and let me know if it works for you.