# Implementing nesting query rather than sub-query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a MS-Access query that interprets dates and provides an appropriate status for given projects.  However, this query provides data on only one division at a time.  I am trying to eliminate the sub-query (highlighted in red below) so I can more easily repurpose the query for other division reports.

[image: query with subquery]

Below is the sub-query, named `qryProjectStatusDPLphase1`:

```sql
SELECT tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.HifFcfCbh
    , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.ProjectNum
    , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_CondCommitDt AS CondCommit
    , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_FirmCommitDt AS FirmCommit
    , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_FundAgtRecdDt AS FundAgt
    , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_InDisbursemtDt AS Disbursemt
    , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_ServicingDt AS Servicing
FROM tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH
WHERE (tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.HifFcfCbh) Like "FCF";
```

The problem I run into is that when I insert the red subquery directly into the larger operation, Access still insists on finding the subquery.  So when I forceably remove the stand-alone subquery from Access entirely, I get an error, "The Microsolft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'qryProjectStatusDPLphase1'..."

[image: query without subquery]

In an effort to identify the problem, I built up the query by adding one piece at a time.  When I run the red subquery all by itself, I get no errors.  When I run the red + blue sections of the query, again I get no errors.  But when I run red + blue + teal sections, **then I get the error**.  My suspicion is that there is something wrong with the way the tables are joined, that prevents red + blue + teal working together properly.

Unfortunately I've spent days on this and can't seem to crack the code, so I was hoping for some wisdom from the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you aliased the inner `qryProjectStatusDPLphase1` query, and you are trying to call it again in the outer query. Unfortunately, it is out of scope for the outer query, so it won't work.

If you don't want to save `qryProjectStatusDPLphase1` as an Access query, you can simply paste the query's sql code into parentheses for the `INNER JOIN`:

```
...
FROM(SELECT tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.HifFcfCbh
        , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.ProjectNum
        , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_CondCommitDt AS CondCommit
        , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_FirmCommitDt AS FirmCommit
        , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_FundAgtRecdDt AS FundAgt
        , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_InDisbursemtDt AS Disbursemt
        , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_ServicingDt AS Servicing
    FROM tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH
    WHERE (tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.HifFcfCbh) Like "FCF"
    ) AS qryProjectStatusDPLphase1, zProjectStatusDPL
)as t
INNER JOIN (SELECT tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.HifFcfCbh
                , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.ProjectNum
                , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_CondCommitDt AS CondCommit
                , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_FirmCommitDt AS FirmCommit
                , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_FundAgtRecdDt AS FundAgt
                , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_InDisbursemtDt AS Disbursemt
                , tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.Stat_ServicingDt AS Servicing
            FROM tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH
            WHERE (tblProject_HIF_FCF_CBH.HifFcfCbh) Like "FCF") AS a
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screen-shot, you're still trying to join the nested query `t` to the subquery `qryProjectStatusDPLphase1`:

```
AS t
INNER JOIN qryProjectStatusDPLphase1 As a
    ON t.ProjectNum = a.ProjectNum
```

You'll need to replace that second instance of `qryProjectStatusDPLphase1` with the nested query.